# HTML external scripts variable access

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If an HTML file has multiple external Javascript scripts, does each script have access to all the variables in the other scripts when the HTML page is loaded? e.g. Can script2 directly reference var1 defined in script1?

Comment: Yes, provided the `var1` is defined in global scope

Comment: As well you can use global variables by using 'window.varname = foo'